# Makefile always runs when target executable is in another folder

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```mk
PROJECT_NAME = algorithms
 
INCL_DIR =./include
 
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -I$(INCL_DIR)
 
SRC_DIR = ./src
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
 
OBJ_DIR = ./bin
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))
 
.PHONY: clean run
 
$(PROJECT_NAME): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
 
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
 
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
 
run: $(PROJECT_NAME)
    $(OBJ_DIR)/$^
```

This Makefile is sitting in my project's root directory, the same directory where `bin/`, `src/` and `include/` are.

The problem is, everytime I run make, the `PROJECT_NAME` target is also ran, even when the executable exists in the `OBJ_DIR`.

After some testing I found that this only happens because I output my executable to the `OBJ_DIR`. If I instead output it to the same directory of my Makefile, this error does not occurs.

My question is, how can I keep the Makefile in my root directory while outputing my executable to the `bin/` without having it compile when there are no changes?

Comment: Change `$(PROJECT_NAME)` to be `$(OBJ_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)` and then `$(OBJ_DIR)/$@` to be `$@`

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but I was curious to whether or not that was my only option.

Comment: Please update your post if you have other considerations you want answered. It's not clear what alternative you are looking for since the above will seemingly do what you want.

Comment: On second thought, this will do with some minor alterations to my code. Thanks for the quick answer.